# How To Merge a PDF File while generating another PDF file using XSL-FO?

Tags: java, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am generating a PDF File using XSL-FO, and I have a scenario where I need to merge a PDF file with the one I'm generating using XSL-FO. **Is it possible to achieve this using XSL-FO?**

This is what I have tried now in my XSL file

```
   <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
     <fo:block space-after="1.4em">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="d:htmlparse(., '', true())/node()"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each>
      <fox:external-document xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/extensions"  content-type="pdf" src='./tobedssssconv.pdf'/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you are getting error messages, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54760130/edit) your question to include them, to give a clearer view of what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the extension element [`fox:external-document`](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/extensions.html#external-document) is meant to be at the same level of `fo:page-sequence` elements, not inside an `fo:flow` with other block-level objects (you are probably getting some validation error while processing your file).

```
<fo:page-sequence>
    <!-- .... -->
</fo:page-sequence>

<fox:external-document .... />

<fo:page-sequence>
    <!-- .... -->
</fo:page-sequence>
```

This way, you will have the pages generated for the first `fo:page-sequence`, then the pages from the "included" PDF, then the pages for the second `fo:page-sequence`.

Otherwise, if you want to insert something between `fo:block` elements, you can use [`fo:external-graphic`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_external-graphic) (inside an `fo:block` or another block-level element).

Either way, you need the [PDF Images Plugin](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fop-pdf-images.html) to reference PDF files as the source for `fo:external-graphic` or `fox:external-document`.